# Complex json parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have following very complex JSON string. I need to select only couple of items from each node like list, cost and unavailable. but Im not getting any idea, how I can fetch each of my desired element. I am using `JSON.NET.`

Json Content :

```
{
  "parts": [
    {
      "1_0": {
        "added2cartStatus": 0,
        "unavailable": true,
        "originalQty": 0,
        "buyQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "nd": [
          {
            "100": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star PalmSpring",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "101": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Indio",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "102": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Metro SB",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "103": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Banning",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "108": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Yucaipa",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "109": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Redlands",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "111": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Riverside",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "112": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Blomington",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "113": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$80.58",
                "cost": "$52.65"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Chino",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "perCarQty": 0,
        "uofm": {
          "100": "EA",
          "101": "EA",
          "102": "EA",
          "103": "EA",
          "108": "EA",
          "109": "EA",
          "111": "EA",
          "112": "EA",
          "113": "EA"
        },
        "sortRequired": false,
        "minQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "costToggleState": 0,
        "updatePartStatus": false,
        "buyInc": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "2_0": {
        "added2cartStatus": 0,
        "unavailable": false,
        "originalQty": 0,
        "buyQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "nd": [
          {
            "100": {
              "selected": true,
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star PalmSpring",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "101": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Indio",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "102": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Metro SB",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "103": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Banning",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "108": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Yucaipa",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "109": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Redlands",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "111": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Riverside",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "112": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Blomington",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "113": {
              "price": {
                "list": "$20.22",
                "cost": "$9.23"
              },
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Chino",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "perCarQty": 0,
        "uofm": {
          "100": "EA",
          "101": "EA",
          "102": "EA",
          "103": "EA",
          "108": "EA",
          "109": "EA",
          "111": "EA",
          "112": "EA",
          "113": "EA"
        },
        "sortRequired": true,
        "minQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "costToggleState": 0,
        "updatePartStatus": false,
        "buyInc": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "3_0": {
        "added2cartStatus": 0,
        "unavailable": true,
        "originalQty": 0,
        "buyQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "nd": [
          {
            "100": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star PalmSpring",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "101": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Indio",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "102": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Metro SB",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "103": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Banning",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "108": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Yucaipa",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "109": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Redlands",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "111": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Riverside",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "112": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Blomington",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "113": {
              "pseudo": false,
              "sellDirect": false,
              "called": "Star Chino",
              "deliveryDelay": "",
              "available": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "perCarQty": 0,
        "uofm": {
          "100": "",
          "101": "",
          "102": "",
          "103": "",
          "108": "",
          "109": "",
          "111": "",
          "112": "",
          "113": ""
        },
        "sortRequired": false,
        "minQty": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        },
        "costToggleState": 0,
        "updatePartStatus": false,
        "buyInc": {
          "100": 1,
          "101": 1,
          "102": 1,
          "103": 1,
          "108": 1,
          "109": 1,
          "111": 1,
          "112": 1,
          "113": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "running": false
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and explain the exact problem you're having so we can build on that. If you have no clue I'd suggest to start with simple examples before diving into complex structures. I'm sure there must be a ton of similar questions in SO.

Comment: Have a look at JsonPath.  http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: I was looking for simple code to accomplish this. I already tried few solutions but they did not work. I am newbie...

Comment: Rent a coder, they did it for you:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [jsonutils.com](http://www.jsonutils.com/), generate json classes, download the newtonsoft from nugets projects and try to use json serialize method.

Comment: thank you. I did this process. Now it will require me to set all values/properties of classes. Is there any way to populate them automatically, since I already have json with me. I need to fetch coupe of values?

Comment: use the Newtonsoft nuget. You can use the JsonConvert.Deserialize<Type>(string json); for instance.